# Splitting field over $\Bbb Q$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have to find out a finite extension $L/\Bbb Q$ such that the polynomial $h(T)=T^3-7T+7$ has a root in $L$; since $h(T)$ has degree 3 and has no rational roots, it is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$. Therefore, I can say that if $L\simeq\Bbb Q[T]/(T^3-7T+7)$ then $L$ is a extension of the type we are looking for.

I construct $\Bbb Q[\alpha]\simeq \Bbb Q[T]/(T^3-7T+7)$, where $\alpha^3-7\alpha+7=0$, and clearly here $h(T)=(T-\alpha)(T^2+\alpha T+\alpha^2-7)$. Can I say that $\Bbb Q[\alpha]$ is one of the extensions we are looking for or should I resolve the equation $h(T)=0$ more explicitly?

Comment: As you expain what you're supposed to find, I think it's enouggh. You may add that $\alpha$ is the congruence class of $T\bmod T^3-7T+7$.

Comment: Thank you very much